# How to get data from ngform in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController" >
    <form name="test_form" ng-submit="submit()">
        <input type="text" name="some_name" ng-model="form_data.some_name" required>

        <ng-form ng-repeat="key in keys" name="keyForm">
            <input type="text" name="data_input" ng-model="form_data.data_input" required>
        </ng-form>  

        <a ng-click="addKey()">NEW KEY</a>
    </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('TestController', function TestController($scope){

    $scope.keys = [];

    $scope.addKey = function() {
        $scope.keys.push({});
    }

    $scope.submit = function() {
        console.log($scope);
    }

});
```

In submit function I can get the value of "some_name" input:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    console.log($scope.form_data.some_name);
}
```

But I can't get the values of "data_input" inputs (they are inside ngform tag). How to do that?
(ngform tag is using for ability to validate each new added input separately)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each input inside the ng-repeat needs its own unique ng-model property -- they all can't use `form_data.data_input`.  Here is one way to solve your problem:

```
<ng-form ng-repeat="key in keys" name="keyForm">
    <input type="text" name="data_input" ng-model="key.data" required>
</ng-form> 

$scope.addKey = function () {
    $scope.keys.push({ data: ''});
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/cFSJ3/).

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/14379763/215945