# Angular Access to Forms Within Directives

Tags: forms, validation, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create some directives for drop down lists: `<drop-down-list />`.

First, I am not sure how to give each `<select>` a unique name. Other SO answers suggest that I can't dynamically name the controls and to instead wrap every `<select>` in its own `<form>` (or `ng-form`).

I cannot perform validation because within my directive's `$scope` I don't have access to the form. Is there a reason why forms aren't showing up in directive scopes? Should I be wrapping each `<select>` in its own form?

This is the template HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form name="formDDL" novalidate>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="ddl">{{title}}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6" data-ng-class="getControlStatus(formDDL.ddl)">
                <select
                    name="ddl"
                    data-ng-options="i.{{keyField}} as i.{{textField}} for i in itemSource | orderBy: orderBy"
                    data-ng-model="model"
                    data-ng-required="isRequiredCallback"
                    class="form-control">
                    <option value="">{{defaultText}}</option>
                </select>
                <span data-ng-show="hasRequiredError(formDDL.ddl)" class="error">{{getRequiredErrorMessage()}}</span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the directive code:

```
application.directive('dropDownList', ['baseUrl', function (baseUrl) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: baseUrl + '/Content/templates/dropdownlist.html',
        transclude: false,
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            title: '@',
            orderBy: '@',
            keyField: '@',
            textField: '@',
            defaultText: '@',
            requiredMessage: '@',
            model: '=',
            itemSource: '=',
            isRequired: '=',
            enableValidation: '='
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.isRequiredCallback = getCallback($scope.isRequired, false);
            $scope.isValidationEnabled = getCallback($scope.enableValidation, false);

            $scope.getControlStatus = function (control) {
                if (!$scope.isValidationEnabled() && !control.$dirty) {
                    return {};
                }
                return {
                    'has-success': !control.$error.required,
                    'has-error': control.$error.required
                }
            };

            $scope.hasRequiredError = function (control) {
                if (!$scope.isValidationEnabled() && !control.$dirty) {
                    return false;
                }
                return control.$error.required;
            };

            $scope.getRequiredErrorMessage = function () {
                return $scope.requiredMessage;
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

You can ignore the `getCallback` function: it just handles the bound value being a boolean *or* a function.

Comment: please, provide Plunker/Fiddle with your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had a combination or issues.

Originally, I thought I could change the name of the control. However, you can't give inputs dynamic names: [Dynamic validation and name in a form with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378401/dynamic-validation-and-name-in-a-form-with-angularjs).

The trick is to give each control a nested form (or `ng-form`) and reuse the same name.

Well, Chrome was caching my template, so the broken HTML was being returned. I set up Chrome developer tools to never cache.

The next problem was that an `<input>` must have `ng-model` defined in order to show up under the form object (`FormController`). That makes logical sense: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#binding-to-form-and-control-state.