# validation of a form added with a directive

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I would like to access the content of the validation variables provided from AngularJS for the forms.
I need to add forms using a directive like in the code, but if I do that I can't access the $dirty,$error,$invalid variables anymore and I need to access them.

JS:

```
myApp.directive('test', function() {
  return {
    scope : {
      nameform: "=",
      nameinput: "=",
      type: "="
    },
    template: '<form name=nameform></form>',
    restrict: 'E',
    compile: function (elem,attr){
      var form = elem.find("form");
      if(attr.type == "text")
        form.html('<input type="text" name="nameinput" ng-model="data.text" placeholder="type here..." required />');

    }
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<test nameform="valform" nameinput="valinput" type="text"/>
{{valform.valinput.$invalid}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can't. Because you are using isolated scope for building your directive, so you don't have acces to the information. You can try to build you directive using share scope, and I think that you would be able to access this information.

Comment: in which way? do you have any suggestions?

Comment: can you show the html that generate your directive?

Answer (score 0):

Change your directive to be ng-form instead of form (because ng-form is nestable).  Then wrap your directive inside another form element and give that new form element a name.  The outer form element will bind to your outer scope and you can access the properties that way.

Directive template:

```
"<ng-form name="valform"></ng-form>"
```

HTML:

```
  <body ng-view>
    <div>Valid: {{outerform.$valid}}</div>
    <div>Errors: {{outerform.$error}}</div>
    <form id="outerform" name="outerform">
    <test type="text"/>
    </form>
  </body>
```

Side note, form names don't play nice with dynamic names.  The plunkr below uses static names so I could help you with your current problem. I found a solution to the dynamic name problem on a different SO post...I think this one...
[Dynamic validation and name in a form with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378401/dynamic-validation-and-name-in-a-form-with-angularjs)

Here's a plnkr with your working form...
http://plnkr.co/edit/RFrRXp2kWkP1Mefwl3Kn?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, but I need also to put the form in a cell of a table, and the table is made with ng-repeat. If I put the test-element in the <td> it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: and I need to see the $scope element in the controller, like
$scope.mainform.innerform1.$dirty, $scope.mainform.innerform2.$dirty, etc...
the big problem I have now is to give a different name each form

Comment: I had to solve the same problem with a form and ng-repeat, with each inner form having a different name.  That's where I made another directive called "dynamicName" which would allow me to assign different names to the inner forms for each iteration of the ng-repeat.  Each of my items has a UUID associated with it, so I used the UUID of each item as the name of each inner form...as well as using the UUID for the name of each input field.  So, I ended up with every input field having its own ng-form around it, then a parent form around the whole thing.

Comment: Here's an example with ng-repeat and a table. http://plnkr.co/edit/RFrRXp2kWkP1Mefwl3Kn

Answer (score 0):

When you build your HTML for your input controls, make sure you append the name attribute correctly based on 'nameinput' passed in as an attribute:

```
myApp.directive('test', function() {
   return {
      scope : {
         nameform: "=",
         nameinput: "=",
         type: "="
      },
      template: '<form name=nameform></form>',
      restrict: 'E',
      compile: function (elem,attr){
           var form = elem.find("form");
           if(attr.type == "text")
                form.html('<input type="text" name="' + attr.nameinput +'" ng-model="data.text" placeholder="type here..." required />');

      }
   };
});
```