# Input validation in a loop not working

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-ng-repeat

With AngularJS, I'm trying to build dynamically a form from a json.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/586pB/2/

You can see in the fiddle that :

- generating form is ok
- auto disabling submit button is ok

But, input validation doesn't work.

`ng-class="{ 'has-error' : entryForm[field.id].$invalid && !entryForm[field.id].$pristine }"`

This code is working when it's not in a loop : `entryForm.title.$invalid`. But not with this syntax : `entryForm[field.id].$invalid`

Thanks for your help.

**Edit : solved**
Found my answer here : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1404
Each form-group is now a form, and each input has a static name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic validation and name in a form with AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378401/dynamic-validation-and-name-in-a-form-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

If you want add error styles to all input-fields in the form (if data on the form not correct), you can do next:

```
ng-class="{ 'has-error' : entryForm.$invalid}"
```

instead

```
ng-class="{ 'has-error' : entryForm[field.id].$invalid }"
```

I update your jsfiddle with correct validation and button-disabling.

**Update:** 
**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/586pB/6/)**

Comment: I'd like a validation for a each field. The user needs to know which field is invalid.

Comment: @odupont, I updated JSFiddle, based on your comment, please see it.

Comment: Much better, but for Bootstrap I'd like "has-error" class on form-group element. I think I'll go with a directive.

Answer (score 0):

In angularJS, your form get parsed before ng-repeat.

So all your form input control get register with name **'{{field.id}}'** instead of its original value like **title or position**. That's why your condition for error class is not validating.

To solve this problem, you can create your custom directive with your field data.

Comment: Thanks, but I've found a better solution here : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1404