# form input validation of a clone with Angular

Tags: forms, angularjs, clone

I'm building an order form with multiple select elements added dynamically.
The validation is handled by Angular, however validation breaks on cloned elements.
Here's a Plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/TqofTw6K7nvLJzPEYAi3?p=preview

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378401/dynamic-validation-and-name-in-a-form-with-angularjs   Short story: looks like there are some workarounds for 1.2x angular, or try out 1.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what Brocco mentioned, cloning the elements won't be the angular way of doing this.
You can do it by following these steps:

1. Create an array to hold all the newly added `<select>` items. e.g. `$scope.dataArray = []`
2. Wrap each form items with an `ng-form` together with an `ng-repeat`, be sure to use this notation:

   `<div ng-repeat="data in dataArray track by $index" ng-form="dataForm"></div>`

   to avoid `ng-repeat` duplicates.
3. Create a scope function to add a new dataArray item, similar to your cloning function.
   e.g:

   `$scope.addItem = function() {
       $scope.dataArray.push({})
     }`
4. Use dataArray[$index].name as the model to get a direct reference of each item in the `dataArray` array

**HTML**

```
        <div ng-repeat="data in dataArray track by $index" ng-form="dataForm">
          <div class="item">
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : dataForm.name.$invalid && submitted }">
                <label>Name</label>
                <select id="name" name="name"  ng-model="dataArray[$index].name" 
                          ng-options="item as item.name for item in items" required></select>
                <p ng-show="dataForm.name.$invalid && dataForm.name.$pristine && submitted" class="help-block">You name is required.</p>
            </div>
            <span class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addItem()"> Add </span> 
          </div>
        </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
  $scope.dataArray = [{}];

  $scope.items = [
          { name: 'Protein 1' },
          { name: 'Protein 2' },
          { name: 'Protein 3' },
          { name: 'Protein 4' },
          { name: 'Protein 5' }
  ];

  $scope.addItem = function() {
    $scope.dataArray.push({})
  }
```

See this [plunker update](http://plnkr.co/edit/KxREJLxsufGdI7DPGyUk?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Don't clone the elements, that's not the *angular* way to do this...

Instead use an `ng-repeat` directive to loop through the items you wish to collect.

As for form validations, please refer to this [article](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/03/angular-js-validating-form-elements-in.html) about validating each item individually by using `ng-form`