# Angularjs validation behaves differently for 1.3.0 and 1.2.6

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-validation

I wish to create a custom directive, which renders as an input type element. The directive should reuse the angularjs validation framework. Following is the `custom-input` directive in action which I have created:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="validationApp">
<body>
  <div class="container" ng-controller="ValidationController as validationController">
    <form name="myForm">
        {{employee | json}}
    <custom-input ng-required="true" ng-model="employee.name" name="employee.name" id="employeeName" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,7}$/"/></custom-input>
    <span ng-show="myForm['employee.name'].$error.required">This is a required field</span>
    <span ng-show="myForm['employee.name'].$error.pattern">This is a invalid field</span>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/templates/customInput.html">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="{{name}}" ng-model="newInput" id="{{id}}">
    </div>
  </script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The javascript corresponding to this is:

```
angular.module('validationApp', [])
.controller("ValidationController", function(){

})
.directive("customInput", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        require : "ngModel",
        replace: "true",
        templateUrl : "/templates/customInput.html",
        scope : {
            id : "@", //bind id to scope
            name : "@" //bind name to scope
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl){
            //When newInput is updated, update the model of original input
             scope.$watch('newInput', function(newValue){
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(newValue);
            });

            //On first load, get the initial value of original input's model and assign it to new input's model
            ngModelCtrl.$render = function(){
                var viewValue = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;
                if(viewValue){
                    scope.newInput = viewValue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I am trying to apply `ng-required` and `ng-pattern` validation on this custom-input. I am running into two problems:

1. In angularjs 1.2.6, I am able to fire `ng-required` validation in the `custom-input` but in 1.3.0, the validation is not getting fired.
2. I am unable to fire `ng-pattern` validation in both versions.

My understanding is that `$setViewValue` of `ngModelController` will fire all the validations. The above is a contrived example, my actual use case is to create a custom directive which renders three input boxes for SSN.

Following is the plunker link for 1.2.6 and 1.3.0 respectively:

[Angularjs 1.2.6](http://embed.plnkr.co/kevTon/preview)
[Angularjs 1.3.0](http://embed.plnkr.co/yNSLdx/preview)

Comment: replace: true parameter is now deprecated. Avoid using it.

Comment: use ng-form. form does not work with nested forms.

Comment: I didn't get you. I don't see any nested forms here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. To get the `ng-required` to work, *don't* have the same name on the input of the inner input form. I appears that in Angular 1.3, this overrides the registered `ngModelController` attached to your `custom-input`.

   So the template for the directive can be

   ```
   <div>
     <input type="text" ng-model="newInput" id="{{id}}">
   </div>
   ```

   This can be seen working at http://plnkr.co/edit/TqMkxV?p=preview.

   (Also, not sure why you need id here...)
2. I think (but I'm not sure) in 1.2.6 `ngPattern` only works on `input` elements, while in 1.3 it's a separate directive that integrates with ngModel. Also, to get it to work in 1.3

   - Use `pattern` instead of `ng-pattern`, even though the docs suggest `ng-pattern` should work.
   - If you're writing the pattern directly  in the template, don't wrap it in `/` ... `/`. So a correct use of it looking for exactly 5 digits would be `pattern="^\d{5}$"`. The docs are misleading in this.

     Your modified 1.3 example, with a working example of `pattern` can be seen at http://plnkr.co/edit/1zSiJI?p=preview

Edit after comments:

3. If you do want the name to appear on the inner directive, and be the same as the parent elements name (e.g. for submitting using standard full page POST to server), you can wrap it in a named `ngForm`. This will ensure that its controller won't override the parent one in the scope.

   ```
   <div>
     <div ng-form name="customInput">
       <input type="text" ng-model="newInput" id="{{id}}" name="{{name}}">
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

   This can be seen at http://plnkr.co/edit/Jrk63A?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the response. How do I replicate the name then? My scenario is not that of a single page application. I have conventional round trip application where data is sent to server using input names. I tried removing the name from custom-input and adding it to the internal input tag but that doesn't seem to register it with the form. Should I use something like dynamicName as described here [http://stackoverflow.com/a/21337430/1014559](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21337430/1014559) ?

Comment: I've added a part about what to do if you want the inner input to have the same name are the parent directive.

Answer (score 0):

In the isolating scope inside the directive, try bind it using '=' instead of '@'

With @, you will need to use attr.$observe('title', function(value) { ... }) if you need to use the value in your link(ing) function. E.g., if(scope.title == "...") won't work like you expect. Note that this means you can only access this attribute asynchronously. You don't need to use $observe() if you are only using the value in a template. E.g., template: '{{title}}'.

With =, you don't need to use $observe.

(FROM [What is the difference between '@' and '=' in directive scope in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050195/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-directive-scope))

```
angular.module('validationApp', [])
.controller("ValidationController", function(){

})
.directive("customInput", function(){
return {
    restrict: "E",
    require : "ngModel",
    replace: "true",
    templateUrl : "/templates/customInput.html",
    scope : {
        id : "=", //bind id to scope
        name : "=" //bind name to scope
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl){
        //When newInput is updated, update the model of original input
         scope.$watch('newInput', function(newValue){
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(newValue);
        });

        //On first load, get the initial value of original input's model and assign it to new input's model
        ngModelCtrl.$render = function(){
            var viewValue = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;
            if(viewValue){
                scope.newInput = viewValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
});
```

Comment: I am not sure why an isolated scope should cause an issue here. I would not want my custom input's model to be exposed to parent scope. In case this custom input is used multiple times, they will collide in scope. Also, I wish to know why is there a difference between 1.2.6 and 1.3.0? And ng-pattern is not getting fired as well. I am assuming that ng-pattern will only fire for `input` tag not for `custom-tag`.

Comment: @Vaibhav If that is the case, bind it using '=' instead of '@'

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried incorporating your suggestion. Please refer the plunker here [http://embed.plnkr.co/FwQFhu/preview](http://embed.plnkr.co/FwQFhu/preview). This still doesn't solve the problem with 1.3.0 vs 1.2.6. Can you share a running code snippet with me, in case I am unable to understand your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

According to the document(https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration),
a regular expression string is used as the value for ng-pattern in angular 1.2. In contrast, a regular expression object is used in 1.3.

```
// 1.2
$scope.exp = '/abc/i'; //string

<input ng-pattern="{{exp}}" ...


// 1.3
$scope.exp = /abc/i; //regexp object

<input ng-pattern="exp" ...
```

Here is my custom input directive example

angular 1.2.16 :

http://jsfiddle.net/miyukiw/m03f2ymt/4/

angular 1.3.5 :

http://jsfiddle.net/miyukiw/9d64oa1m/4/

I hope this will be of some help.