# Angular Forms - How to register inputs with dynamic names?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L8m7ptm7/

I have an array of objects that represent questions I'd like to include within an Angular form:

`$scope.questions = [
    {
        'name': 'question1',
        'label': 'Question 1',
        'value': null
    },
    {
        'name': 'question2',
        'label': 'Question 2',
        'value': null
    }
];`

The questions are rendered correctly within the DOM - with `name` attributes of `question1` and `question2`, as desired.

The trouble arises when attempting to read these field's values out of the `myForm` object. Run the fiddle, and you'll see what happens. Instead
of the form containing keys for `question1` and `question2`, it contains a single key - `{{question.name}}`.

Is it possible to have these fields register with the form object using the desired (rendered) names?

[image]

Comment: have you seen this posting:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378401/dynamic-validation-and-name-in-a-form-with-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

I was at Angular 1.2. Upgrading to Angular 1.3.6 results in the desired behavior.