# Why does setting ng-model to undefined not make the form/input valid again?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-ng-model

I have the following simple form with an type='email' input bound to a model:

```
<div ng-app>
    <h2>Clearing ng-model</h2>
    <div ng-controller="EmailCtrl">
        <form name="emailForm" ng-submit="addEmail()">
            <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="userEmail" placeholder="email@domain.com">
            <span ng-show="emailForm.email.$invalid && emailForm.email.$dirty">invalid email</span>
            <span ng-show="emailForm.$invalid">form invalid!</span>
        </form>
        <br/>
        <button ng-click="clearViaUndefined()">clear via undefined</button>
        <button ng-click="clearViaNull()">clear via null</button>
        <button ng-click="clearViaEmptyString()">clear via empty string</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Suppose the user enters an invalid email but then clicks a 'Cancel' button...so the form needs to be reset.

In the ng-click handler for the 'Cancel' button, if I set the value of the model to 'undefined' this does not change the input element's $valid property back to true (nor the form's for that matter).

```
function EmailCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.clearViaUndefined = function () {
        $scope.userEmail = undefined;
    };

    $scope.clearViaNull = function () {
        $scope.userEmail = null;
    };

    $scope.clearViaEmptyString = function () {
        $scope.userEmail = "";
    };
}
```

If I set the value of the model to an empty string "" or to null, then the $valid property does get set back to true.

Why is this?

I have a JS Fiddle here demonstrating the behaviour:

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/12830/

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem -- All the buttons clear the input form for me ... (Chrome).

Comment: It is only a problem if you enter an invalid email - because I am trying to reset the $valid status of the form from 'false' back to 'true' - so if you enter a valid email, then the $valid value is already 'true' - hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Whenever you use ng-model on an input or select tag, angular internally manages two values for the field, one is `$viewValue` and other is `$modelValue`

> $viewValue -> Used for display purpose on view
>
> $modelValue-> Actual value which is used inside scope.

When using an input tag with `type='email'` Angular constantly validates the input value.

And if the value does not validate as a correct email, angular internally will set `$modelValue` to `undefined` and will set the form.fieldName.$error.fieldName attribute to true. So that field becomes `invalid`.

If you check the value of form.fieldName.$modelValue inside the controller you will find it as `undefined`.

So setting the model to 'undefined' in the controller, when the field is already invalid, changes nothing.

But if you set it to `null` or `""` it will work as `$modelValue` and `$viewValue` both get changed - making the field valid again.

Hope this has cleared your understanding. Thanks.

Comment: how can i show error messages like "Required field" when field is blank or "Invalid email id" when field has invalid email?

Comment: I am checking the validation in controller and showing the message from controller. For invalid email, i am always getting blank data, so it is showing "Required field" every time. Can i show different messages by using controller.

Comment: thanks a lots. but i have a lots of form and rendering them using ng-repeat on  form fields. i am using validation.js for every form validation. I am not using angularjs form validation. i am setting $scope.errors.[field.name] = "massage" by using validation.js. Can i achieve by using javascript validation.

Comment: @rajeshpanwar  Surely there should be a way to do it..for that i need to look at code..please Do create and Question with plunkr/jsfiddle.. here it is not good place to solve the issue.. :)

Comment: @rajeshpanwar take a look at this somewhat similar rendering form inside ng-repeat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118134/angular-directive-with-dynamically-generated-input-fields-not-able-to-display-va/28146946#28146946

Comment: I have created an simple example of myform. Please look at it : http://plnkr.co/edit/EHf2REss3qNbDo9SCRCK?p=preview

Comment: @rajeshpanwar I already told you that, do open one separate question, so  i can help you out there..

Answer (score 5):

Add ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}" on input field

then try setting ng-model to undefined hopefully will make the form/input valid again

see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions