# $watch does not watch model when using scope attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working on a directive made for `<input>` that watches what the user types. When the user types in a valid phone number it should re-format the input model object and set a variable to true, indicating to the parent scope that the model now contains a valid phone number.

`CountryISO` is depency injected as constant and contains - surprise - the country code of the user. The functions used inside the directive are from phoneformat.js

**UPDATED:** Now the valid = true/false assigment works. But how do I then update the actual model value? This needs to be changed to the properly formatted phone number.

```
app.directive('phoneFormat', ['CountryISO', function (CountryISO) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                require: 'ngModel',
                scope: {
                    valid:'='
                },
                link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

                scope.$watch(function() {
                return ngModel.$viewValue; //will return updated ng-model value
                }, function(v) {

                if (isValidNumber(v, CountryISO)) {

                    // What do I do here? This doesn't work.
                    v = formatE164(CountryISO, v);
                    // This neither
                    ngModel.$viewValue = formatE164(CountryISO, v);

                    console.log("valid");
                    scope.valid = true;

                } else {

                    console.log("invalid");
                    scope.valid = false;
                }
                });
                }
            };
        }]);
```

as the directive

and the html looks like:

```
<input data-phone-format data-valid="user.validPhoneNumber" data-ng-model="user.info.ph">
```

The problem is that as soon as I include `scope: {valid:'='},` as part of the directive, the $watch stops working. How do I get both? I want the directive to be able to point to a variable in the parent scope that should change from true to false depending on the validity of the phone number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because as you declaring watcher the variable are parsing with the directive scope which becomes isolated scope after you have added `scope: {valid:'='}` to make it working you could place watch on the `ngModel.$viewValue`

To updated the `ngModel` value you could set `$viewValue` of ngModel using `$setViewValue` method of `ngModel` & then to update that value inside `$modelValue` you need to do `$render()` on `ngModel`.

Read on [**$viewValue & $modelValue**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28338146/2435473)

**Link**

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

    scope.$watch(function() {
        return ngModel.$viewValue; //will return updated ng-model value
    }, function(v) {

        if (isValidNumber(v, CountryISO)) {

            // What do I do here? This doesn't work.
            v = formatE164(CountryISO, v);
            // This neither
            ngModel.$setViewValue(formatE164(CountryISO, v));
            ngModel.$render(); //to updated the $modelValue of ngModel
            console.log("valid");
            scope.valid = true;

        } else {

            console.log("invalid");
            scope.valid = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: $viewValue comes from where? Is this something I must declare somewhere?

Comment: @nickdnk it came from `require`, you need to add that inside link function parameter..look at the updated answer..

Comment: $viewValue is a property on the ngModelController, which you `require`-d.

Comment: Ok. Cool. It works. Does that mean I don't need element and attr as arguments?

Comment: @nickdnk no you meant it wrong way..I said that `require` of directive options like you specified here `require: 'ngModel',` you have to add `element` & `attrs`, the 4th parameter would only be `requireController` or `transcludeFn` depends what you are doing

Comment: @PankajParkar Yes - your changes made the watching work properly. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Amazing. Exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @nickdnk Glad to help you..Thanks :) you could read up on linked answer for more into on `$viewValue` & `$modelValue`