# AngularJS form validatation of auto-generated form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I am trying to validate an auto-generated form (via `AngularJS v1.3`) which inputs' names are in format:

```
form_name[field_name]
```

The very basic example would be:

```
<form name="morgageCalculator">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
            name="morgageCalculator[homeValue]" value="0"
            data-ng-model="data.homeValue" required="required"/>
</form>
```

As you can see, the input name is `morgageCalculator[homeValue]`. Now I would like to add an error message below it:

```
<div class="error"
     data-ng-show="!morgageCalculator.morgageCalculator[homeValue].$pristine && morgageCalculator.morgageCalculator[homeValue].$invalid">
    Please enter a number
</div>
```

For very obvious syntax reasons this expression is not valid:

```
morgageCalculator.morgageCalculator[homeValue].$pristine
```

But this one also does not work:

```
morgageCalculator["morgageCalculator[homeValue]"].$pristine
```

So, **the question**, is there any sane way of accessing those fields? I wouldn't mind moving the validation to some controller function, but I was faced with same issue of inability to access field object.

Any help/hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28146946/2435473 would help you

Comment: The thing is, the form is not generated from within `AngularJS`, but in `Symfony` PHP framework, so the names are correct...

Comment: It should be `data-ng-show="!morgageCalculator['morgageCalculator[homeValue]'].$pristine && morgageCalculator['morgageCalculator[homeValue]'].$invalid"`

Comment: @JovanPerovic name attribute should have interpolation `ng-attr-name="{{morgageCalculator[homeValue]}}"`

Comment: @dfsq That is the correct syntax. In fact, due to copy/pastes, I somehow left out `data-ng-model` attribute. After adding it back, everything started working :) Thanks!

Comment: @PankajParkar No, I have no desire to resolve names client-side...

Answer (score 1):

With help of @dfsq from comment section, I was able to find the error. Unlike my SO question, my code was missing `data-ng-model`.

**Validation will not fire at all if input was not bound to model....**

The correct snippet:

```
<form name="morgageCalculator">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
        name="morgageCalculator[homeValue]" value="0"
        data-ng-model="data.homeValue" required="required"/>


    <div class="error"
        data-ng-show="!morgageCalculator['morgageCalculator[homeValue]'].$pristine && morgageCalculator['morgageCalculator[homeValue]'].$invalid">
            Please enter a number
    </div>
</form>
```