# Access $error in Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an input wrapped in a directive with a dynamic name like this:

```
<input class="input-field" name="{{name}}" type="number" ... />
```

Now I want to access the `$error` variable of the form IN the directive.
Something like `form.{{name}}.$error.number`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What did you try? Also, show us more of the context.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378401/dynamic-validation-and-name-in-a-form-with-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the form (that is on the parent scope) you have to pass the form to your directive. To do this, you have to specify that you want two way binding (using `=`) when you define your directive.

Have a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive, more specifically the part about [isolating the scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive) can probably help you.

Comment: That I know. But I does not know how I can access the specific field on the form dynamically. The field's name is stored in a variable...

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question then. Have you tried `form[name].$error.number` ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's enough to get the `$error` of the specific `ngModelController`?

```
return {
  template: '<input ng-model="value" type="number" /><span ng-bind="error | json"></span>',
  scope : {},
  link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
    scope.error = elem.find('input').controller('ngModel').$error;
  }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/wzuWT1lVevCLHkLLBIAT?p=preview