# access angularjs form field that contains a number

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have a list of form fields that are generated as the result of an `ng-repeat` . As such I use the {{$index}} of the repeat loop to name the fields, i.e. `  which leads to:

```
<input name="myInput0">
<input name="myInput1">
<input name="myInput2">
...
```

etc. Now I'm trying to access the fields' `$valid` attribute from the form in the standard angularjs way i.e. `myForm.myInput{{$index}}.$valid` which resolves to e.g. `myForm.myInput0.$valid` which I understand won't work because it's accessing a variable and numbers won't be allowed.

However I then tried to access it with `myForm['myInput{{$index}}'].$valid`, e.g. `myForm['myInput0'].$valid` which I thought might work but still doesn't. Is there any way possible to access the form field when it contains a numeral? (or other illegal char like a hyphen)?

e: I'm using angularjs 1.2 which might explain why this isn't working. Does anyone know of a workaround for pre 1.3 angular?

Comment: from what I know it is possible to do this kind of thing `myForm.myInput0.$valid` even if it ends with a numeral

Comment: can you add a plunker or jsfiddle of it?

Comment: I've just realised that it's probably the version of angularjs I'm using, I'm stuck on 1.2.19 and I beleive what I'm trying to do was only available in 1.3+?

Answer (score 0):

The correct expression will look like `myForm['myInput' + $index].$valid`

Comment: Would I be correct in thinking this won't work in angularjs 1.2? I forgot to mention that initially in the question.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. This works in 1.3+. 1.2 does not support dynamic names for inputs.

Comment: fair one, you answered the question I originally asked so if noone has a workaround by tomorrow I'll check this as answered

Comment: I believe here you'll find what you ultimately want to achieve - [Dynamic validation and name in a form with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378401/dynamic-validation-and-name-in-a-form-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways of workaround.

First option:

Put a ng-change on each input and validates it there manually.

Second option:

Retrieve all input elements, interate over each and validates manually

You can get them with this

```
var inputs = $document[0].querySelectorAll('#rankingForm input');
```